# How can I get y-axis category labels to appear in a bar chart when the category has no x values?

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, visual-studio-2015, reporting

I have a bar chart in my report which, on the x-axis, reflects the percentage of all answers which fall into a category, and on the y-axis, reflects the categories:

[image]

There are two more categories which are not showing on the y-axis: "Weak" and "Very weak", each of which recieved zero answers, and so have a 0% value.

I still need those two categories to appear on the y-axis, though, and have not been able to make that happen.

EDIT at @R.Richards' request:

The graph is being created by drawing data from this query:

```
SELECT multiple_choice FROM mytable
```

...where `multiple_choice` is a field with values between 1 and 5.

The chart category is `multiple_choice`, and the values are based on the expression

```
=Count(Fields!multiple_choice.Value) / Count(Fields!multiple_choice.Value, "ChartName")
```

FURTHER EDIT following a comment from @iamdave:

As values for the categories "Very Weak" and "Weak" were not selected at all in the dataset, the only place the categories appear is in the Labels - which are created with an expression:

```
=iif(Fields!multiple_choice.Value = 1, "Very weak",
 iif(Fields!multiple_choice.Value = 2, "Weak",
 iif(Fields!multiple_choice.Value = 3, "Somewhere in the middle",
 iif(Fields!multiple_choice.Value = 4, "Strong", 
 iif(Fields!multiple_choice.Value = 5, "Very strong", "")))))
```

Comment: Can you add to this question the query for the dataset that this chart uses?

Comment: @R.Richards edited to suit.

Comment: Does your dataset actually return a row for the `Weak` and `Very Weak` category?

Comment: @iamdave now that's a pretty good point. Because there are no rows that include any values for those two categories, they do not - have edited my question to elaborate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A chart can only display categories for which there is data to display from your dataset.  If the answer categories do not exist in your database you will need to hardcode a `union all` into your dataset with `0` values where appropriate.

The preferred solution - assuming your database *does* contain a list of all the possible answers - would be do write your query in a way that first returns all the possible answers and then aggregates against them, instead of going straight to the given answers, as your dataset appears to be doing now.

---

Assuming a table structure of:

- Questionnaires

  - Which holds all the details about a particular questionnaire.
- Questions

  - Which holds all the questions for each questionnaire.
- QuestionAnswers

  - Which holds all the possible answers for every question.
- Answers

  - Which holds a record for each Answer that has been selected.

---

```
select q.QuestionnaireName
      ,qu.QuestionName
      ,qa.QuestionAnswer
      ,count(a.Answer) as Responses

from Questionnaires q
    inner join Questions qu
        on q.QuestionnaireID = qu.QuestionnaireID
    inner join QuestionAnswers qa
        on qu.QuestionID = qa.QuestionID
    left join Answers a
        on qa.QuestionAnswerID = a.QuestionAnswerID

where q.QuestionnaireID = @YourReportParameter

group by q.QuestionnaireName
        ,qu.QuestionName
        ,qa.QuestionAnswer
```

---

This query would output - for the given Questionnaire - every single possible question, every single possible answer and a count of how many times that answer was chosen.  Obviously this doesn't cater for free text or numerical responses but I'm sure you can work that out if required.

Comment: Thanks, @iamdave - this helps a great deal, and will inform my design for this sort of DB going forward. I appreciate your taking the time to break this out for me!